# How to add a URL to the begining of every fetch request in my application?

Tags: reactjs, http-proxy-middleware

I have a react app started with **CRA**, and a **backend server** set up for my react app.

My fetch requests go something like

```
const res = await fetch("/applications", {
...
```

I have set it up my app with a proxy middleware using **http-proxy-middleware**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'https://projects.mydomain.com/', 
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

When I make a request to the backend using `fetch("/applications")` my request get's parsed as `fetch("/projects.mydomain.com/applications")`

However I need to add a url path to the begining of all my fetch requests, my final desired result is:

`fetch("/projects.mydomain.com/b2b-iys/applications")`

I tried doing this:

```
  app.use(
    '/b2b-iys/',
    createProxyMiddleware("/b2b-iys", {
      target: 'https://projects.muhammed-aldulaimi.com/', 
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
```

But that didn't work.

I would ideally like to add it to my proxy rather than change the files one by one.

What's the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

From the http-proxy-middleware [documentation](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-middleware-options) I think you can use the `pathRewrite` option to add a base path :

```
app.use(
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'https://projects.mydomain.com', 
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {'^/': '/b2b-iys/'}
  })
);
```

Comment: When I did that, after starting the application I got redirected to my home page (https://projects.mydomain.com) instead of react local development build.

Comment: I also noticed that this behaviour is a result of using http-proxy-middleware library, when I use the default proxy option in my package.json provided by CRA, when a connection fails to establish it still displays my application on my original react port (300)